# User model with Allauth social signup in django?

Tags: django, model, django-allauth, user-accounts

I have a custom user model in which i added a **role field** to. If i add an allauth social login with Facebook will the **role field** be asked upon login with Facebook?

Comment: Add a custom signup form, as documented [here](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#socialaccount-forms)